# How to Set content length of mail in AIX

Tags: unix, jakarta-mail, aix

We have a java utility which is used to extract mail attachments in Unix. Its running fine in Solaris environment. It takes input as mailbox file location which contains the mail stored as a queue. Based on the subject which is passed as arguement it finds the mail in mailbox file and extract the attachement and copy it some defined remote location in unix.

The problem I am facing is that when I try to run the same utility in AIX environment. There is a field called content-length which was coming in the mail messages in Solaris environment but its absent in AIX environment. Can someone tell me how can we set the content-length in AIX environment ?

Answer (score 0):

The Content-Length header is a UNIX-specific extension originally introduced in System V UNIX, so I'm surprised that AIX is no longer using it.

Are you reading the file in [UNIX "mbox" format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox)?  Are you using the [JavaMail mbox provider](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/MboxStore)?  It should work both with and without the Content-Length header.

Comment: Can you suggest other utilities which we can use to extract attachements from mail in unix and store them to specified remote location ?

Comment: I'm sure there's many.  Have you heard of this web site called "Google"?  :-)  But if you're having trouble getting JavaMail to work for this, answer my questions above and provide more information about what's going wrong.